# Best practice for getting all child game objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

**Hello :-)**
I'm new developer in **Unity3D.** 
I have a question what is the best practice of getting all children GameObject.

[image: GameObject's hierarchy]

I wanna active or de-active 3 buttons (Camera, SNS, Save Buttons) under some conditions.

here is my code to do that. but I think this is not good.
I would like to replace it. There are so many foreach statements.
When the parent game object will be added, foreach loop will be added also.

---

```
var uiRoot = GameObject.Find("UIRoot");
    if (uiRoot != null)
    {

        foreach (Transform camera in uiRoot.transform)
        {
            camera.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            foreach (Transform anchor in camera.transform)
            {
                anchor.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                foreach (Transform buttons in anchor.transform)
                {
                    if (buttons.gameObject.tag == "PictureTag")
                    {
                        buttons.gameObject.SetActive(!isCameraVisible);
                    }
                    else if (buttons.gameObject.tag == "CameraTag")
                    {
                        buttons.gameObject.SetActive(isCameraVisible);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Do you guys have a good idea for that? 
Help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to grab all the components within the child gameobjects then you can use something like this:

```
var uiRoot = GameObject.Find("UIRoot");
if (uiRoot != null)
{
    bool includeInactiveGameobjects = true;
    var buttons = uiRoot.GetComponentsInChildren<UIButton>(includeInactiveGameobjects);
    foreach (UIButton uibutton in buttons)
    {
        // Do stuff to button here:
    }
}
```

This creates a collection of Button components that can be iterated through and their associated gameObjects can be accessed by using the gameObject property on the component within the foreach loop:

```
...
foreach (UIButton uibutton in buttons)
{
    // Do stuff to button here:
    GameObject gameObject = uibutton.gameObject;
}
```

Cheers!